# How can I dynamically get the fields on an image media bundle?

Tags: 8, media

What’s the correct way to get all of the key/values for a bundle on a media entity?

I am trying to create a media entity programmatically and I need to get all of the fields on the image bundle. I am not sure how to get the image bundle ID either.

In other words, I’d like the module I'm working on to be a bit more generic and reusable as I’ve seen the image bundle have different names depending on the installation.

Here’s what I have so far but the two main problems I see are that the image bundle ID can change and the field names on the bundle can be different.

```
   $entity = $this->createFile(
      $uri,
      $file[0]['filename'],
      $file[0]['filesize'],
      $this->currentUser
    );
    $entity->setPermanent();
    $entity->save();
    // Save media entity
    $media = [
      'bundle' => 'image',
      'uid' => $this->currentUser->id(),
      'status' => 1,
      'image' => [
        'target_id' => $entity->id(),
        'alt' => t(basename($file[0]['filename'])),
        'title' => t(basename($file[0]['filename'])),
      ],
    ];
    $image = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('media')->create($media);
    $image->save();
```

I'd like to be able to get the `image` bundle and dynamically figure out whichever field has the `target_id` and then assign the previously created file entity to that. I do not know how to get the image bundle schema, array signature, in order to traverse the key/values to find the target_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can traverse the field definitions of the media bundle `image` and look for a field with the type `image`:

```
$fields = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('media', 'image');
foreach ($fields as $key => $field) {
  if ($field->getType() === 'image') {
    // found image field $key
  }
}
```

To get all media bundles:

```
$bundles = \Drupal::service('entity_type.bundle.info')->getBundleInfo('media');
```